# PDO insert, foreach($_POST)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My code below will not insert into my database. I do not know where my misstake is being made. (Thanks for the notifications regarding sql injections, will read about that laters <3)

This is my php code so far:

```
$sqlArray = array();
$nameArray = array();
$valueArray = array();

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    //$sqlArray[] = "':".$name."'=>$".$name;
    $nameArray[] = $name;
    $valueArray[] = "'".$value."'";
}

$names = implode(', ', $nameArray);
$values = implode(', ', $valueArray);

$sql = "INSERT INTO random ( ".$names." ) VALUES ( ".$values." )";


$addRandom = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$addRandom->execute();
```

And the output by $sql looks like:

```
INSERT INTO random ( random1, random2, zipCode) VALUES ( 'Namn', 'Adress', 'Zipcode' )
```

What should I change or add?

Comment: ლ(ಠ益ಠლ) Y U NO use parameterized queries?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And exactly what do you want us to do? YOu've provided **NO** details about WHAT you're trying to do.

Comment: @Joel the exact structure of your `$_POST` array is not provided.  This makes your question Unclear and by effect very hard to confidently provide an accurate answer.  Your accepted answer is not using a prepared statement effectively to combat injection vulnerabiliites/instabilities.  Please clarify your question so that superior answers can be provided to this old, low-value page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prepare your query properly, and set you connection error mode, everything else seem okay:

```
/* Very very important !!*/
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$names = implode(', ', $nameArray);
$values = implode(', ', ':'.$nameArray);

$sql = "INSERT INTO random ( ".$names." ) VALUES ( ".$values." )";
$addRandom = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    $addRandom->bindValue($name, $value);
}

$addRandom->execute();

if($addRandom->rowCount > 0){
    echo 'INSERTED';
}else{
    echo 'FAILED';
}
```

**note**
Your `$_POST` keys should match the field name you are binding to, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: This is still vulnerable to inserting / affecting rows other than those defined by the HTML form, since there is no validation done on `$nameArray`.

Comment: yes indeed, op can put the field names into an array an check if they belong to it. or maybe sanitize with  regex. not sure the best way I dont usually build the sql manually

Comment: Thanks for the help! Regarding your note, seemed to be missing one row in db... Pretty big table, easy to miss...

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the PDO library, which is good for starters, however you aren't exactly utilizing the communication method as it would be adequate:

```
$sqlArray = array();
$nameArray = array();
$valueArray = array();

$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO random ([[tablename]]) VALUES (?);";

$whiteList = array(
    'random1',
    'random2',
    'zipCode',
    ...
);

function whiteListedColumn($whiteList, $columnName){
    if (in_array($columnName, $whiteList)){
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function prepareStatement($dbHandler, $templateSQL, $columnName){
    $completeSQL = str_replace('[[tablename]]', $columnName, $templateSQL);
    return $dbHandler->prepare($completeSQL);
}

try{
    foreach($_POST AS $name => $value) {
        if (whiteListedColumn($whiteList, $name)){
           $prepStmt = prepareStatement($dbh, $insertSQL, $name);
           $prepStmt->execute(array($value));
        }
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error has occured while inserting data.";
}
```

I've refactored the insert query to incorporate a wild-card binder which we will be using at the `execute` step (passing in an array of values to be bound to the appropriate places in the query indicated by `?` marks).

You are passing in the colum names, so to sanitize them, we aren't going to take the route of manually escaping any bad characters, but we will take the route of comparing the input to a whitelist of accepted column names predefined - that way, anything that is 1) not threatening the consistency of your database, 2) semantically valid for your database will be allowed, everything else will result in the execute portion absolutely neglected.

Comment: Appriciate it! Though the last foreach makes it insert one value to one column and creates one billion rows.

Been trying to solve it by my self, but lack of skills is putting it to a stop...

Comment: True indeed - we could make use of the `lastInsertId()` function of the PDO database handler, however your `random` table would need to have unique index column serving as a primary key. That would allow us by making a slight modification (to check if an insert has been made and retrieve the new row's ID) to avoid the problem of "a billion rows". If you would decide to add an ID (or it is plausible at all in your case), by also adding some transaction handling to the mix, you would also have your IDs safe for multiple inserts at a time.