# PDO Insert foreach

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

I am trying to insert an array of values multiple times into a table.

I have a simple array that is generated by a user checking a box and that's what gets added to the array, I then want to insert each value into a table, I thought I could do it with a foreach loop and iterate $i but it appears I can't, I don't need to worry about security or anything as this is internally used by two people.

here is what I have:

```
foreach($detailsinvoice as $desc){ 
  $conn3 = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO 
             xero_invoices (ContactName, Description)
             VALUES (:ContactName, :Description)";  
  $st3 = $conn3->prepare ( $sql3 );
  $st3->bindValue( ":ContactName", $this->ContactName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st3->bindValue( ":Description", $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st3->execute();
  $this->InvoiceNumber = $conn3->lastInsertId();
  $conn3 = null;
}
```

This was my first attempt but gathered that the connection can only be used once then exits, so I tried an iteration but again I learnt that you can't do that with the PDO statement.

```
$i = 3;
foreach($detailsinvoice as $desc){ 
  $conn[$i] = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
  $sql[$i] = "INSERT INTO 
             xero_invoices (ContactName, Description)
             VALUES (:ContactName, :Description)";  
  $st[$i] = $conn[$i]->prepare ( $sql[$i] );
  $st[$i]->bindValue( ":ContactName", $this->ContactName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st[$i]->bindValue( ":Description", $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st[$i]->execute();
  $this->InvoiceNumber = $conn[$i]->lastInsertId();
  $conn[$i] = null;
  $i++;
}
```

`detailsinvoice` is the array and the ContactName will be the same each time (the Contactname works just need to figure out looping the array)

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: _gathered that the connection can only be used once_ Where did you get that idea? Does thsi mean we are talking about a Scope issue?

Comment: Do __not__ set `$conn3` to null and use it as many times as you need.

Comment: You really only need 1 connection for your whole request / script and if you use `bindParam()` instead, you can put everything before the `execute()` statement before the loop. How you handle the results is something else, `$this->InvoiceNumber` will not mean much after the loop.

Comment: There is no need for many mysql connection to exist. You can/should use same connection. And you did not mention what is the real issue you had faced to? You just shared your assumption that you can't do something. but thereis no description of what exactly did you failed to acheive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO insert, foreach($\_POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729671/pdo-insert-foreach-post)

Comment: Maybe you should show us a `var_export($detailsinvoice);`

Comment: Or maybe you should show us the WHOLE CLASS as I get the feeling this is very relevant to your problems

Comment: Or at least the WHOLE METHOD that this code lives in

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, The answer you and u_mulder gave below seems to be what I am after, I can't believe I was so caught up on having the foreach before the Insert statement rather than just the values. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature of prepared statements is that you can **prepare** a statement **once** and then execute it multiple times, so your code can be rewritten as:

```
// Create a connection
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        xero_invoices (ContactName, Description)
        VALUES (:ContactName, :Description)";  
// Create a statement
$st = $conn->prepare ($sql);
foreach ($detailsinvoice as $desc) { 
    // bind values and execute statement in a loop:
    $st->bindValue( ":ContactName", $this->ContactName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Description", $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $this->InvoiceNumber = $conn->lastInsertId();
}
// this is optional
$conn = null;
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for yours and @RiggsFolly asnwers. Once I saw both your answers it started to make sense. when coming across something new it's hard to get my head around how to make it work but using the foreach where you have makes totally sense and it seems to be doing what I expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you got the idea a connection can only be used once from. You should connect only once in a script. Then as long as you store and pass around the `$conn` variable to any functions you may use (Scope of course is relevant here) you can use it as many times as you like.

```
// connect ONCE per script
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

// write the query once
$sql = "INSERT INTO xero_invoices (ContactName, Description)
             VALUES (:ContactName, :Description)";  

// and prepare it once.
$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );

// now loop over the array of parameters any number of times you like
foreach($detailsinvoice as $desc){ 

    $st->bindValue( ":ContactName", $this->ContactName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Description", $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();

    // this line looks wrong, as $this->InvoiceNumber will get overwritten
    // each time round the loop
    //$this->InvoiceNumber = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // maybe you ment this, so at least you would have them all???? 
    $this->InvoiceNumber[] = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // or I have to assume you are going to add another query HERE
    // that will use that ID
}
```

The concept of a prepared statement is that it is passed to the database, compiled, optimised and saved in the database almost like a stored proceedure.

Once prepared it can be used again and again. All you do is put new values into your parameters each time you execute it.